# Plot time series of paired columns

Tags: python, plot, time-series, multiple-columns

I have an excle file and would like to create time series plots. For a quick view of data for one site, caputred image is give below. I would like to plot two categories of data - one is modelled and the other is monitoring data. For example, "pH" and "pH data" on one plot, "WQ[SO4,Dissolved]" and "WQ data[SO4,Dissolved]" on one plot, as such for all the remaining 30 paires. That means 60 columns of data to plot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIG41.png)

```
My approach was:
1) read excel data as DF;
2) creat a list for each category of parameters to plot
3) use the "zip" function to creat a paralle list: parameters_pair = zip(parameters_model,parameters_monitor)
4) plot, some codes shown below.


for i,j in parameters_pair:
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7)
    ax.plot(df_Plot['Tstamps'], df_Plot[i],
                label=site, color='blue', linestyle='solid') #fillStyle='none'
    ax.plot(df_Plot['Tstamps'], df_Plot[j],
                label=site, color='orange', marker='s', markersize='4', linestyle='')


My code can plot for i or j individually but if it does not put modelled and monitoring data on one plot and iterate paralelly as expected. Could you please suggest what functions to use to solve this issue? Thank you very much.
```